# Was able to/manage vs could?

Tags: grammar, can-vs-be-able

Why is this sentence correct:
"Could you find Diana's bag?"
According to what grammars say, it should be:
"Did you manage to find Diana's bag?"
Because:
1.it indicates ability in a particular moment.
2."find" is not a perception verb.
3.there is no negative limiting adverb.
4.it does not occur in a subordinate clause.
I found this example in an activity and it marks as wrong the second example but not the first one,but I still can't understand why.

Comment: I don't understand the explanations either, but "Could you find Diana's bag?" sounds more like a request to search for it than an enquiry as to whether or not it has been found. If the searcher _could/was able to_ find it, they _did_ find it, so it would be more natural to ask "Did you find Diana's bag?"

Comment: The restrictions on the use of _could_ that you list apply to affirmative statements. So the sentence _?After looking for Diana's bag all morning I could find it under the bed_ is of dubious grammaticality. But the restrictions do not to apply to negative statements, and seem not to apply to questions. Here is an answer about _affirmative could_ containing references on the topic from pedagogic and descriptive grammars: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112433/ability-in-past-for-positive-and-negative-sentences/116132#116132

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had not considered the possibility that it might indicate "request" rather than ability.That could explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Could you find Diana's bag?" and "Did you manage to find Diana's bag?" are both grammatically correct but mean (at least) 2 different things. Unfortunately, "could" is a difficult word to master because it has so many different meanings and usages, and a lot of the differences are subtle.

"Could you find Diana's bag?" is the colloquial/idomatic form of a request to find the bag (i.e. "Please find Diana's bag") and how most native US English speakers would interpret the meaning of that sentence, though some people find that usage irritating because of its literal meaning, which is "Is finding Diana's bag a task you are able to accomplish?" Those people would prefer to be asked "Would you find Diana's bag?"

In the literal case, "could" is the past tense of "can" but is not being used as a past tense but rather, as is true with many other modal verbs, the past tense is used to indicate some tentativeness or probability in the present. People can and do as "Can you find Diana's bag?" but the definiteness of "can" makes that request more forceful and therefore impolite for the people who accept the idiomatic sense of the word, and it really irritates the people who focus on the literal meaning because by forcefully asking "can you do something" the speaker is implying that they (the speaker) believe you (being spoken to) cannot do it. With "could", they are at least saying they think it is reasonably possible or perhaps even likely that you can.

"Did you manage to find Diana's bag?" assumes that you previously indicated that you would look for it but somehow expressed uncertainty about whether or not you would be successful, and the speaker is now asking for an update on that later activity.

Answer (score 0):

**could you find** can refer to a general state of affairs in the past:

> When you lived on the tundra in Alaska, could you find enough food to eat?

However, your example with "Diana" and the search for her bag,  if it is not a request (i.e. *Could you please find ...*) would seem to refer to a *discrete* incident in the past, since we don't generally look for Diana's bag as a habitual or regular practice:

> Could you find Diana's bag?  <sup>unidiomatic when not a request</sup>

and you are correct that the usual ways to ask a question about a particular incident in which someone was searching for something:

> Were you able to find it?
>
> Did you manage to find it?
>
> Did you find it?

That isn't to say that we couldn't concoct a scenario where the question was idiomatic; we'd just have to make the search something regular:

> When we were first going out, Diana refused to believe I had ESP, and she would test me by hiding her bag and then demanding I find it.
>   -- Well, could you find it without ransacking the place?

Comment: For me, there's nothing problematic about a question such as: "_Could you find that bag you were looking for yesterday?_, although "_Did you find ...?_" is probably more common.

Comment: @Shoe: "were looking for" mitigates the issue.  The continuous makes it not a discrete event but a series of events, an ongoing thing. Do you feel the same about *Could you find that bag you wanted to find?* or *Could you find that bag you needed?* or *Could you find your dog that ran away?*

Comment: You make an interesting point. But I still don't find anything too objectionable about the three questions. It would be interesting to hear other opinions on this. In the meantime I'll see if I can find anything in my grammar reference books.

Comment: @Shoe: I think the answer of yours, which you cited in the comment at the top of the page here, gets at the issue where you're quoting Huddleston and Pullum: "... **could** does not normally appear in affirmative contexts when it is a matter of actualisation of *a single situation viewed perfectively*" [my emphasis]

Comment: Is a question an affirmative context? I'm not sure. But at the risk of belabouring the point, I see nothing problematic, for example, in asking a friend who has just returned from holiday: _Could you find a nice place to stay?_

Comment: @Shoe: When the semantics of the situation allow for an imperfective view of the action, it doesn't create aspectual dissonance with **could** in the way that a perfective view of the action does: *Could you find your dog that ran away?* is asking about the ultimate outcome of the search, and I don't think you find **could** OK there, whereas *Could you find a nice place to stay?* admits the meaning "Were there a number of nice places to choose from?" which isn't a perfective view of the lodgings search. It's not really asking "Was the place you ended up in a nice one?"

Comment: You make a fine distinction between the two sentences. And, yes, I am belabouring the point now, but in the context of knowing that my neighbour's dog had run away and that she spent the morning looking for it, I see nothing particularly problematic about asking: _Could you find your dog yesterday?_. Ok, I'll bow out at this point but will be interested in other opinions.

Comment: @Shoe: I keep making the distinction between imperfective and perfective because that distinction is critical to understanding aspectual interactions with **could**.  The word **yesterday** again turns the question at least to a degree into an imperfective one--as you say, she "spent the morning looking for it".  I happen to find that question marginal or borderline.